# Question about brahmacharya recommendations and rules

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, yoga, yoga-sutras, brahmacharya

So my question is there are many text about brahmacharya and they may also be with some rules and recommendations.
[https://www.swaminarayan.faith/scriptures/en/satsangi-jeevan/prakran-5/52#:~:text=A%20Brahmachari%20(celibate)%20should%20take,of%20hair%2C%20on%20his%20head](https://www.swaminarayan.faith/scriptures/en/satsangi-jeevan/prakran-5/52#:%7E:text=A%20Brahmachari%20(celibate)%20should%20take,of%20hair%2C%20on%20his%20head).
+pantajali yogasutra brahmacharya + many more descriptions by bhisma in mahabharat etc.

So my question is if we read all text, we will find that we can't follow everything in brahmacharya?

***Opinion:many things are recommendations for brahmacharya and not rules [correct me if I am wrong please]***

> .So  I ask you to differentiate rules and recommendations? I. E.  Tell basic rules first which are must to follow and then the recommendations in scriptures

---

Reason for my opinion :many scriptures suggest different lifestyles for brahmacharya. And a normal student in gurukul might not be able to do all activities of brahmacharya Or have all qualities of brahmachari (ie. Not perfection is likely to be achieved)

Comment: It would be better if you answer from yog sutras, vedas or mahabharat as puranas have lot of prakshipt

Comment: Concept of brahmacharya has changed over thousands of years. In modern times its meaning is narrowed down to sex. What I find fascinating is that most of the brahmacharya talks and texts do not even address the Bramhan. Attaining Bramhan or Moksha is the ultimate goal; brahmacharya is one of the tools.